# Python 2.7: Read binary data from buffer object and base64 encode it

Tags: python, base64, buffer

I have a 3rd party method that has a returns object of type buffer:

```
<read-write buffer ptr 0x02CED2E0, size 2556 at 0x02CED2C0>
```

This should be a binary data. How can I read from the buffer and then base64 encode it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Probably it's an object with buffer interface. See also [buffer()](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#buffer).

If you need only to encode it, without any processing beforehand, then see [base64 module](http://docs.python.org/2/library/base64.html):

```
import base64
b64encoded_str = base64.b64encode(your_buffer_object)
```

This should work fine.

If for some reason this won't work, then `str` (in Python 2.7) takes `buffer` objects as input and transforms to `str` object, so:

```
import base64
b64encoded_str = base64.b64encode(str(your_buffer_object))
```

or even simpler, though it might introduce newline character '\n' in the end:

```
b64encoded_str = str(your_buffer_object).encode('base64')
```

Comment: `b64encoded_str = base64.b64encode(your_buffer_object)` works fine. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

for a data type， no specified binary format to represent it. this depends what you want,

for example， can you try pickle.dump,then base64 to encode this bin data ?
or JSON